# Postgresql query not able to add column where the column name is similar to an SQL keyword?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an list of internal names for different columns I need to add, and one is named `end` which causes an issue since this is an sql keyword.

```
  DO
  $$
  BEGIN
  IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM information_schema.columns
                        WHERE table_schema = 'public'
                          AND table_name = lower('entity')
                          AND column_name = lower('end')
                      ) THEN
            ALTER TABLE public.entity
            ADD COLUMN "end"  TEXT NULL;
  ELSE
            ALTER TABLE public.entity
            ALTER COLUMN "end" TYPE  TEXT;
  END IF;
  END
  $$;
```

I seem to have read some posts where the end keyword can be used as a column if it qouted,
but this still fails?

The error message i get is :

```
MessageText: syntax error at or near "end"
```

Why?

Comment: What is the exact error you get?

Comment: Perhaps it should be `"END"`, or `"End"`...

Comment: Added the errror message, @jarlh the name `end` is predefined to be like this `end`

Comment: `NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM` has no select-list. That's a syntax error.

Comment: @jarlh not sure I understand the issue here?

Comment: You have to select something, e.g. SELECT 1 FROM...

Comment: I am not interested in value, just whether there exist an column for the given condition.. 
if yes, it return one row, if not it wil return no row

Comment: @jarlh: The SELECT list can stay empty for this purpose in Postgres. In fact, that's best.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, I see. I'd probably put a 1 there, a small effort to keep portability.

Comment: The error you show is not in Postgres format, you edited it. Please show the actual complete message as returned from using the function. The code(modified as to table name) worked here in `psql`. Where are you running this code?

Comment: Your DO statement works for me.  A column with the unfortunate name is added to the table "entity".  I am guessing that you are using some client other than `psql`, and whatever it is is tripping over its own feet.  `HeidiSQL`, maybe?